# My users are getting 302 Found page if they don't write https in address bar, how can I prevent this?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, html, url, apache

I host a forum website in DigitalOcean's cloud servers, using Ubuntu 16.04, Apache 2.4.20, PHP 7.0.8 and MySQL 5.7.12.

I tried to troubleshoot with cURL about what is the problem, these are the results:

[image]

And this is the .htaccess of the root directory (/var/www/html/)

[image]

HSTS is enabled, and my forum uses HTTPS address as the main board URL.

Comment: A 302 response requires a `Location:` header.   You have somehow configured your server to respond with that status, but without the header.   The lack of the redirect location is the problem.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Since the `L` flag is missing on the `RewriteRule`, the request will be (internally) rewritten again, which I guess is probably messing up the redirect (ie. absent `Location:` header). (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you add `[R=301,L]` after your RewriteRule in your .htaccess to redirect the visitor, like so:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Currently your telling the browser "*There is a https version I want you to visit*". The `R=301` adds "*I want you to go there via a 301 reload*". It's the reload part you don't have in place currently.
The `L` stands for "Last", after this line it will not excecute the remainder of your htaccess, it will start the reload. After the reload this line is skipped.

Comment: Okay, I added your code and these are the results: http://i.imgur.com/4QrHJwN.png

Comment: So now it should work fine and redirect to the main URL?

Comment: Apache will implicitly do a 302 redirect when specifying an absolute URL in the `RewriteRule` substitution. However, because the `L` flag is missing the request is being rewritten (again) and "messing up" the redirect. (But yes, a 301, rather than a 302, should be used for such redirects anyway.)

Comment: I just opened the site (which you could've done yourself) and it redirects

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help. I appreciate it a lot.